# Where can be found all MenuProps attributes of a Select in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Having the next Material UI Select, I've found that one can modify its behavior and appearence.

```
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

class SimpleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: 10
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.age}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        inputProps={{
          name: "age",
          id: "age-simple"
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

This is the above one with MenuProps added, also a [sandbox where I'm playing with it](https://codesandbox.io/s/18l2042y97?file=/demo.js:0-1038).

```
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

class SimpleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: 10
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.age}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        inputProps={{
          name: "age",
          id: "age-simple"
        }}
        MenuProps={{
          anchorOrigin: {
            vertical: "bottom",
            horizontal: "left"
          },
          transformOrigin: {
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "left"
          },
          getContentAnchorEl: null
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

My question is: where can I find all the possible attributes (like anchorOrigin, transformOrigin, etc) available for it?

I want to make the dropdown wider and also to add checkboxes for each dropdown item but I don't know what MenuProps attributes to access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The starting point for finding this is the `Select` API documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/select/. Within the [Props](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props) section you will find `MenuProps`:

> MenuProps     `object`      Props applied to the [Menu](https://material-ui.com/api/menu/) element.

In the above, the word "Menu" links to the `Menu` API documentation. You may look at that and say "but where is `anchorOrigin` and `transformOrigin`?"

At the end of the [Menu Props API](https://material-ui.com/api/menu/#props) documentation, you will find the following:

> Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element ([Popover](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/)).

In the above, the word "Popover" then links to the `Popover` API documentation (where you will find `anchorOrigin` and `transformOrigin`).

At the end of the [Popover Props API](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/#props) documentation, you will find the following:

> Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element ([Modal](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/)).

Similarly, in the above, the word "Modal" links to the `Modal` API documentation. So the full props available on `Menu` are the combination of all the props documented for `Menu`, `Popover`, and `Modal`. There is some work in progress to improve the documentation to provide more direct access to all the applicable props: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18288.